# Tinyscrollbar how to move thumb

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, draggable, tinyscrollbar

I am looking for a solution that must have been a task for a lot of people before me. Now, Tinyscrollbar is very, also for touchscreens. I use it on a very larg Screen in a store and the srollbar is very big.

The first thing people are trying to do is, move the content by dragging the tumb of the scrollbar. But it's not working. Tinyscrollbar doesn't come with that option. Or am I completely wrong?

So, I'm trying things with jQuery Draggable to make the thumb moveable. But how to update the content according the position of the thumb?

It seems like a very complicated, hacky task. But I wonder if there is a simple solution for that which I'm not seeing.

I already emailed to the developer, but there is no response.

edit: so I found out, that the drag works fine in FF but not in Chrome. I could use FF, but there the swipe gestures don't work, which work in Chrome. Which is strange, because here (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) it works and here (http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/examples/simple/) it only marks the text. I can't see the difference.

So thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing weird inconsistencies with tinyscrollbar between browsers. Are you still struggling with this problem? If not how did you solve it?